# How to ensure images are loaded inside a JQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, image, plugins, webkit, google-chrome

While creating a JQuery plugin that required image dimensions, I discovered that webkit browsers like Chrome often return 0 size for images because they're loaded in parallel.

My quick and dirty solution was to wrap the code that calls my plugin in a `$(window).load()` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.magnifier').magnifier();
    });
});
```

How would I go about implementing this inside the plugin itself?  What is the cleanest way to detect that images have loaded so I can measure their dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images have a load() event, so you could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.magnifier').magnifier();
});

$.fn.magnifier = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).find('img').load(function() {
            // do something to image when it is loaded
        });
    });
}
```

You could also simply wrap the code around window.load inside the plugin itself:

```
$.fn.magnifier = function() {
    var that = this;
    $(window).load(function() {
        that.each(function() {
            $(this).find('img').each(function() {
                // image would be loaded at this point
            });
        });
    });
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand completely but this will fire after all images are loaded.

```
$("img").load(function() { 

});
```